# Lifetime issue using `anyhow` crate in combination with `nom` crate

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having an issue with lifetimes that I'm not sure how to solve, since it seems like the change I'm making should be trivial with regards to lifetimes.

Given:

```rust
use anyhow::Context;
use nom::{IResult, bytes::complete::tag};
```

The following code compiles:

```rust
let input = std::str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).unwrap();

let mut lines = input.lines();
let branch_line = lines.next().context("no output from `git status`")?;
let branch: IResult<&str, &str> = tag("On branch ")(branch_line);
let (branch, _) = branch.expect("failed to get name of current branch");
```

After changing the `expect` in the final line to `context`, the code no longer compiles:

```rust
let input = std::str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).unwrap();

let mut lines = input.lines();
let branch_line = lines.next().context("no output from `git status`")?;
let branch: IResult<&str, &str> = tag("On branch ")(branch_line);
let (branch, _) = branch.context("failed to get name of current branch")?;
```

```
error[E0597]: `output.stdout` does not live long enough
   --> src/status.rs:303:41
    |
303 |         let input = std::str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).unwrap();
    |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
307 |         let branch: IResult<&str, &str> = tag("On branch ")(branch_line);
    |                     ------------------- type annotation requires that `output.stdout` is borrowed for `'static`
...
436 |     }
    |     - `output.stdout` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Looking at the docs for `anyhow`, it doesn't appear to me like it should introduce any lifetime bounds on the `&output.stdout`.

```
fn context<C>(self, context: C) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    C: Display + Send + Sync + 'static,
```

Scratching my head. Still new to lifetimes.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You say it compiles for you; it doesn't for me. It says `cannot find value 'output' in this scope`. Apart of that, you can't directly execute code in Rust, you need to write it in a `main()` function. I know this seems nitpicky, but it's a way of respecting the SO community; the time that you saved by not writing a minimal reproducible example means that now I have to do it before I can start answering your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the type of `branch`, which is `IResult<&str, &str>`.

If you look at the implementation, you can see that this is an alias for `IResult<&str, &str, nom::error::Error<&str>>`, which again is an alias for `Result<(&str, &str), nom::internal::err<nom::error::Error<&str>>>`.

This seems complicated and all, but the main point I'm trying to make is that `branch` is a `Result` type, and the `Err` case of it has the type `nom::internal::err<nom::error::Error<&str>>`. With other words, the error carries a `&str`.

This is on purpose, because ownership is a big problem for nom. This is strongly related to [these known problems of the current borrow checker](https://crates.io/crates/polonius-the-crab). Nom solves this by returning ownership back through the `Err` type.

That sadly means that it is incompatible with `anyhow`. The error types of `nom` are meant to be consumed by `nom`, or at least manually converted into something else before raised into user code.

To explain the exact error you are getting:

- `output.stdout` is a local variable
- `input`, and everything else behind it, is referencing the data in `output.stdout`
- The `Err` variant of `branch` is still referencing `output.stdout`
- `.context()`, or to be more precise, the `?` behind it, tries to return the `Err` variant out of the function, which fails because it still references `output.stdout`, and the reference would then outlive the data it references.

This is not a problem for `next().context()`, because the `None` value of `next()` does *not* carry a reference to `output.stdout`.

One way to fix this is to break the reference by converting the `&str` from the `Err` type to an owned `String`:

```
use anyhow::{Context, Result};
use nom::{bytes::complete::tag, IResult};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let input = "aaaaaa".to_string();

    let mut lines = input.lines();
    let branch_line = lines.next().context("no output from `git status`")?;
    let branch: IResult<&str, &str> = tag("On branch ")(branch_line);
    let (branch, _) = branch
        .map_err(|e| e.to_owned())
        .context("failed to get name of current branch")?;

    Ok(())
}
```